# Printing the contents of the canvas tag

Tags: printing, opera, html5-canvas

I make an application canvas. I load more image (png, gif) in canvas. When I click print on my browser (opera), the contents of the canvas tag does not print. With other browsers (FF, IE, Chrome), there is no problem. Why?

Comment: This is a lot like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217377/print-out-of-a-html5-canvas although personally I don't like the answer there.

Answer (score 3):

this answer from [Capture HTML Canvas as gif/jpg/png/pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf) might be useful.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var img    = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

with the value in IMG you can write it out as a new Image like so:

```
document.write('<img src="'+img+'"/>');
```

Comment: +1. Not sure why Opera doesn't print canvas elements, but converting to an img via this method solves the problem. Plus, the user can save the image to a file, should they want to. :)

Comment: Thanks fro +1.. glad I could help someone!