# How to print a HTML page along with canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am working on a HTML5 project.I have a container (div) and some shapes (canvases) drawn on container.
How can I print the whole document(div + canvas) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217377/print-out-of-a-html5-canvas

Comment: It explains that how to get a canvas data (using dataUrl). But not how to get all body element in printing page.