# Print error in canvas with filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, screenshot

I have a canvas element with some filter and I would like to print this canvas, but when I try, the print hasn't the filter effect.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <canvas id="outCanvas" width="300" height="200" style="position: absolute;">
    </canvas>
    <canvas id="print" width="300" height="200" style="position: absolute; left: 300px;">
    </canvas>
</div>
```

JS:

```
// canvas for video frame
var outCanvas = document.getElementById('outCanvas');
var outCtx = outCanvas.getContext('2d');

var print = document.getElementById('print');
var printCtx = print.getContext('2d');

var image = new Image();
image.onload = function() {
    outCtx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 300, 200);
    printCtx.drawImage(outCanvas, 0, 0, 300, 200);
}

image.src = 'http://www.beach-therapy.com/images/Arubabeach.jpg';

var filter = 'grayscale(100%) sepia(0%) contrast(130%) brightness(110%)';
$(outCanvas)
    .css('filter', filter)
    .css('-webkit-filter', filter);
```

[Fiddle with the example](http://jsfiddle.net/italoborges/y46d2v34/)

Anyone knows something about why this happen?

Comment: you need to convert the canvas item into a png or other image format and print that. You cannot directly print canvas content. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17009946/how-to-print-a-canvas-element for an example (there are many results for "js print canvas")

Comment: @scrappedcola, thanks for your answer. I tried now with converting the canvas and still the same.
Another Fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/italoborges/fLxp78xt/).
The code doesn't work in JSFiddle because security, you have to run in a local server.

Comment: also you should consider applying the filter directly from the canvas context check http://stackoverflow.com/a/31907255/3702797

Answer (score 1):

That's because you have not added filter for **print** div. You have added the filter only for **outCanvas** div.

```
$(print)
    .css('filter', filter)
    .css('-webkit-filter', filter);
```

Now it works. Check the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rqxksuru/).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey bozzmob, thanks for your answer, but you didn't understand. I need to print the image with effect to save this later for the user. Because of that, I can't apply the effect in a print div.