# Printing fabricjs canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I've been struggling for a few weeks on creating functionality to allow me to print my fabricjs canvas. I've tried the methods [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17009946/how-to-print-a-canvas-element) without luck. I'm able to get to the print dialog, however, it's blank aside from the title and page info. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I'm currently using:

```
// Trying to print
function printCanvas()  
{  
    var dataUrl = document.getElementById('c').toDataURL(); //attempt to save base64 string to server using this var  
    var windowContent = '<!DOCTYPE html>';
    windowContent += '<html>'
    windowContent += '<head><title>Print canvas</title></head>';
    windowContent += '<body>'
    windowContent += '<img src="' + dataUrl + '">';
    windowContent += '</body>';
    windowContent += '</html>';
    var printWin = window.open('','','width=340,height=260');
    printWin.document.open();
    printWin.document.write(windowContent);
    printWin.document.close();
    printWin.focus();
    printWin.print();
    printWin.close();
}
```

---

```
<button onclick="printCanvas()">Print</button>
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do the print operation after the content is loaded. The following code should work

```
function printCanvas() {
    var dataUrl = document.getElementById('c').toDataURL(); //attempt to save base64 string to server using this var  
    var windowContent = '<!DOCTYPE html>';
    windowContent += '<html>'
    windowContent += '<head><title>Print canvas</title></head>';
    windowContent += '<body>'
    windowContent += '<img src="' + dataUrl + '" onload=window.print();window.close();>';
    windowContent += '</body>';
    windowContent += '</html>';
    var printWin = window.open('', '', 'width=340,height=260');
    printWin.document.open();
    printWin.document.write(windowContent);
}
```

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to increase the size of the image that it captures from the DataURL? If you'd like I can open a new question. Thanks!

Comment: I couldn't tell

Comment: Tried to give you a solution in your other question.Let me know if that helps

Comment: It did! Thank you kindly. :)

Comment: Very nice. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: @user700284 How to append multiple canvases and setting the page dimensions (pages to be printed) dynamically ?