# JQuery Generated QRCode Disappears When Printing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, media-queries, qr-code

I have generated a QRCode using [this](http://jeromeetienne.github.io/jquery-qrcode/) Jquery Library.

```
$('#myid_info_barcode').qrcode();
```

The code above generates a qrcode canvas in `myid_infor_barcode`.

```
<div id="myid_info_barcode" class="myid_print_duo_barcode">
   <canvas width="256" height="256"></canvas>
</div>
```

[image]

When I printed it using `window.print()` and `media print css` using the CSS code below, the QR Code disappears in the print Preview.

```
@media print {
    .myid_print_duo_barcode
    {       
        margin: auto; 
        border: 1px solid black;   
    }
    .myid_print_duo_barcode > canvas{
        width: 98px !important;
        height: 100px !important;  
        border: 1px solid red; 
    }    
}
```

Where am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Does it print with the render in `table` option?  A quick search shows other people having problems printing `canvas`, eg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217377/print-out-of-a-html5-canvas

Comment: Aren't you supposed to be all knowing? -_^

Comment: you will need to convert the canvas into an image using toDataUrl()